# PHP to get input fields sent by a form (without knowing which field was submitted)

Tags: php, forms, post, input

I have a form with around 15 input fields with a default value each coming from a db table. A Javascript checks whether a field has been modified or not upon submission.

Then my question comes:

How can I get only the submitted values so I can use them to update the table in the database?

Here is a part of my code:

FORM:

```
<form method="post" action="controlPanel.php">
<input name="color_base2" value="<?php echo $info['color_base2']; ?>"></span>
<button type="submit" name="updateItem" value="<?php echo $info['id_item']; ?>" class="updateButton" />UPDATE</button>
```

I know for sure that only the updated values will be submitted, but I don't know which ones are those and need to get them and put each of them in a PHP variable called the same way as the inputted field was called...

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is still unclear to me. What have you tried?

Comment: Why not just parse the whole form and check if it has been changed server side?

Comment: using javascript you can't know if the user really changed the field or not (the user can change the field than returns back the old value) unless you strore the bd value in javascript variable than compare values when submitting the form, than just send the changed data.
or you can grap the data from your db and compare them with the data comming from the form than just update the fields with the new data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you could have your javascript function put the modified data into a json object and send the object to your php function. In your php function you can use the object rather than individual variables for each field.